# How to make an executable File

Tags: java, python, windows, cmd, exe

Everybody probably has used install .exe files. But how to make them and when does it make sense to make one?

For example, I would have had programmed commercial software in Python, c++, etc. with different files a GUI and pictures and all of the other stuff.

When I want to deliver my product to my customer I don't want to give them a folder and say you need to install Python or Java and execute the program via your command line.

How can I create an executable file that installs the required language and sets up local instances and arranges all files into the correct order?

Comment: You are asking a language specific question as if it were language agnostic. Note that if something is open source, there are limitations in your ability to incorporate them in closed-source commercial products.

Comment: Hmm ok, so the procedure is different in any language? 

What would it be like Python?

Comment: So if I would write a web scrapping tool with selenium and beautiful soup, I would not be able to include it into my exe file?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Py2exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an executable file from a python program, there is pyinstaller. I don't know about java at the moment. The command is as follows :

```
pyinstaller fileName.py
```

You can add args (and there are 2 really helpful ones) :

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w fileName.py
```

--onefile will put everything into one single file (recommended) and -w will prevent the console from opening when running the .exe file. Add it if you're running a GUI or something. If you need to console for input, don't add -w.

If you want to automate a command line in cmd, create a shortcut leading to C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe and add /k and your command. For example :

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /k ipconfig
```

Double clicking on the shortcut will now run the cmd and execute ipconfig automatically. If you want more than one command, you can do command_1 && command_2 && ... && command_n

Answer (score -1):

There is a setup program built into Windows.

Type

```
iexpress
```

and follow the wizard.

You need to provide code to run when it finishes to actually install the extracted files.;